# UML Designer SDK 7.1.0.201611211357 inside Ecipse Oxygen 4.7.0 - Missing Representation Types

Tags: eclipse, types, is-empty, representation, uml-designer

UML Designer SDK 7.1.0.201611211357
Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0
Missing Representation Types

Empty representation types selection window using these (both most actual) versions.
Workaround with migration to UML Designer 4.0 is functioning in the first step but causing error messages when creating a model package hierarchy denying me any further actions ...

Is there another workaround or is there something to add to my configuration to make it run?

Comment: I have to add that I'm using Eclipse Oxygen for Java EE ...

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of the error messages.

Comment: Beim Start des UMLDesigners:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-08-07 11:08:29.138
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Gerd'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

Comment: Beim Anlegen einer Package Hierarchy: Root exception:
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "IS_DETACHMENT" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the referring class, org/eclipse/sirius/business/internal/session/danalysis/DanglingRefRemovalTrigger, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for the field's resolved type, com/google/common/base/Predicate, have different Class objects for that type ..

Comment: much more lines in the error-log, but not able to post them here because of limited characters to post. I can send you the error-log file if preffered ;-)

Comment: Eclipse is installed in the mentioned sub-Folder, but Workspace-folder is defined separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install the nightly version which is a beta version of the 8.0. There is version incompatibility due to Guava between UML designer 7.1 and Eclipse Oxygen. This is fixed in the 8.0 version which will be released at the end of the month.